# Online accounts option is not responding on ubuntu 22.10 gnome 43

Tags: gnome, 22.10

I want to add my Google Drive to sync a specific folder on my home PC to access it from anywhere. I processed to do that by adding my Google account to the gnome online accounts, but sadly it's not working. Would you please help me find a solution.

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 gnome 43

Thanks in advance

[image: 1]

Answer (score 5):

Disabling compositing mode seems to work around the issue:

```
export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1
gnome-control-center online-accounts
```

Answer (score 1):

So the only way i found it to work is to download the new evolution through the snap store add your accounts through that and boom they're everywhere

Answer (score 1):

I just used killall gnome-control-centre
and re-opened settings, then it started responding.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue, In my  Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, I simply removed gnome-control-center by `sudo apt purge gnome-control-center` and reinstalled it by `sudo apt install gnome-control-center`,then open the settings and login to Google which solves the problem .

During reinstall a new package named **gnome-online-accounts** is installed, I think so this missing package causes the problem.

Hope someone found this helpful